# Flink or kafka stream in case where any change in stream result in processing all data

Tags: apache-flink, apache-kafka-streams, flink-streaming

I have a use case where lets i get balances based on date and I want to show correct balances of each day. If get an update on older date all my balances of that account from that date gets changed.
for eg

> ```
> Account   Date    balance  Total balance
> IBM       1Jun    100      100
> IBM       2Jun    50       150 
> IBM       10Jun   200      350
> IBM       12Jun   200      550
> ```

Now I get a message of date 4 Jun (this is the scenario some transaction is done back dated, or some correction and its frequent scenario)

> ```
>  Account   Date    balance  Total balance
>  IBM       1Jun    100      100
>  IBM       2Jun    50       150
>  IBM       4Jun    300      450 ----------- all data from this point changes
>  IBM       10Jun   200      650
>  IBM       12Jun   200      850
> ```

Its a streaming data and at any point I want the correct balance to be shown for each account.
I know flink and kafka are good for streaming use case where if an update of a particular date doesnt trigger update on all data from that point onwards. But can we achieve this scenario as well efficiently or is this NOT a use case of these streaming tech at all ?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify a past message in the queue, therefore you should introduce a new message that invalidates previous one. For instance, you can use an ID for each transaction (and repeat it if you need to modified it). In case you have two or more messages with the same ID, you keep with the last one.

Take a look to [KTable](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/concepts.html#streams-concepts-ktable) from Kafka Streams. It can help you to aggregate data using that ID (or any other aggregation factor) and generate a table as a result with the valid resume until now. If a new message arrives, table updates will be emitted

Comment: Yes, With workaround like republishing the entire stream from that point we can do it, but my question is, would it be effecient or this use case this for a different technology

Comment: Well, if an back dated record is produced, one can still update all future account balances -- the key would be "accountId + date". Using the Processor API this would be possible if the store hold the balance per account per day. And corresponding updates messages can be written into a result output topic.